# Can see private beta question with a direct link without being logged in, but can't see more than 5 comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, private-beta

When given full direct link to a question in a private beta site I can see it just fine even without an account there. For example [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1022/email-client-that-supports-markdown):

> [image]

(note that post ID isn't enough, e.g. `https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1022` leads to the generic "Warning: this site is currently in private beta" page)

Now the problem is when clicking "show [x] more comments" I get a blank screen and JS errors in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: openid is not defined
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Where the second error is repeated every second until the page is refreshed.

Also recorded it happening: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9UDvOQfZ7g

Can this please be fixed?

Given direct link to a hidden comment (that should auto expand the list) e.g. [such link](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1022/email-client-that-supports-markdown#comment2277_1022) cause the question to show for a second then blank screen.

Browser is Chrome 32.0.1700.107 m under Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have stumbled on one of the few questions that this would happen with - try pretty much any other question and you would get the beta access notice.

In terms of the comments not expanding - seeing as you were not part of the private beta (i.e. anonymous user), things not working on the page is kind of expected.

I've made a change that makes our URL handling stricter for private beta access, so this loophole is now closed.

Comment: Cheers! One last thing, I can still access the question via the iOS app and appear to even be able to add comment... didn't try though. Is this by design, or another loophole? (e.g. API doesn't check if private beta)